# array used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, initialization

My task is to allocate memory for an array of integers (n elements), to give random values to each one of them and to print them sorted and unsorted. When I compile the code, I get this warning "'v' is used uninitialized in this function", and when I try to run it, I get "Segmentation fault".

I was wondering why am I supposed to initialize the array if I want to fill it up with random values? Is there a problem in the way I allocate memory for the array?(I'm not sure about the cast i did)

This is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, max, n, *v, aux;

    scanf("%d%d", &n, &max);

    *v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        srand(time(NULL));
        v[i]=rand()%max;
    }

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if(v[j]>v[j+1]){
                aux=v[j];
                v[j]=v[j+1];
                v[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ", v[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could make me understand what I do wrong, and eventually modify part of the source.

Comment: I saw what I did wrong, the "*" before v should have been deleted.

Comment: you should also put srand() out of for loop

Comment: You should work on a simpler problem first. It seems you aren't familiar with the c basics (i.e. pointer syntax).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You also have some other problems in your code. (1) don't cast the return of `malloc` (2) don't put the call to `srand` inside your loop (3) be more careful when copy-pasting code, e.g you start with `"#"`

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo (I presume) when creating the array.

```
*v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

The warning

> 'v' is used uninitialized in this function

is because of the deferencing `*v` in the line above.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: As a lesson warnings ***are*** helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

`*v=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));`

You assign the address of your allocated memory to the *dereference* of v - that is, you dereference your uninitialized pointer, and write to "wild memory".

In addition, using unitialized *values* is still a rotten way to get randomness. Look up `rand()` in your manual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look up in the manual. I have spotted another mistake i did. If the srand(time(NULL)) is located in the loop, I'll get the same value for all the elements of the array.